# Displaying a vector of values wrapping at screen width [Shiny]

Tags: html, css, dataframe, datatable, shiny

I have a vector of values and each value is associated with a name; length of vector changes as per the user input. Although I used `table` related commands, I like to know other ways to display this kind of data, which is essentially a vector (a single row) of values with names). The problem shows up when selected sample size produces the output that is greater than screen width. Scrolling horizontally allows flexibility to glance over the data, but I am looking for a solution that wraps up the data at the screen width and prints in multiple rows without the need to scroll. Here is the code to play:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
   tabPanel("Test",
            numericInput("samsize","specify sample size",4,1,52),
            tableOutput('table')
   ))

server <- function(input, output) {

   data <- reactive({

      # create a vector of lower- and upper- case alphabets
      # create a vector assigning numbers to alphabets
      alphabets <- c(letters,LETTERS)
      Index <- seq(1,length(alphabets),1)
      names(Index) <- alphabets

      # sample values
      SampleIndex <- sample(Index,input$samsize)

      # convert it into a matrix
      data <- matrix(SampleIndex,nrow=1)
      colnames(data)=names(SampleIndex)

      data
   })

   output$table <- renderTable(data(),digits = 0)

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

As you see in the below picture, for a sample size '36' one need to scroll the page horizontally to see all the values.[image: screen shot]

`width` in `renderTable` did not offer any solution

Converting data into a html object/text might be one option, but not sure how to retain the names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `renderUI` together with `uiOutput` to create yourself the HTML object you want to display for example using `div`:

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  tabPanel("Test",
           numericInput("samsize","specify sample size",4,1,52),
           uiOutput('myTable')
  ))

server <- function(input, output) {
  data <- reactive({
    alphabets <- c(letters,LETTERS)
    Index <- seq(1,length(alphabets),1)
    names(Index) <- alphabets

    # Notice I don't put the vector in a one row matrix as in you example
    sample(Index,input$samsize)
  })

  library(purrr) # map is a nice alternative to lapply
  output$myTable <- renderUI(map(names(data()),~div(strong(.),
                                                    div(data()[.]),
                                                    style="float:left;padding:10px 20px;")))
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: Formatting related commands for both names and values of the element are really useful.

Comment: in `purrr::map()` when using `~` to declare the function being mapped, `.` is called **it** and is a reference to the parameter passed to the function, ie it refers to each individual value of the vector `names(data())`. So `data()[.]` refers to each value in the vector (indexed by its name). And `div` simply wraps it into `<div> </div>`

Comment: Do you see any logic so that one can combine output of _map_ element and some HTML tags, and generate `uioutput` display such that any text below it starts from a new line. Here is the question in detail: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41470353/display-of-text-in-a-new-line-below-the-uioutput-display-shiny