# display of text in a new line below the uioutput display [Shiny]

Tags: html, css, datatable, shiny

`uiOutput('myTable')` followed by `p("Here is some text....")` puts the text next to `uioutput` display, but I like to print the text in a new line starting from left side of the page. Adding `br()` is simply adding empty space equivalent to screen width, therefore, text starts from a new line but not from from the left side of the page. Interestingly, adding any control widget, e.g., `dateInput` displays the widget in a new line. In my case, `uioutput` input comes from `map` [ *package* `purrr`]. I combined `map` output and `HTML("<br>")` via `list`, but no solution. Here is reproducible code:

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
   tabPanel("Test",
            numericInput("samsize","specify sample size",4,1,52),
            uiOutput('myTable'),
            #dateInput("date", label = "Today's Date")
            #br(""),
            p("Here is some text...")
   ))

server <- function(input, output) {
   data <- reactive({
      alphabets <- c(letters,LETTERS)
      Index <- seq(1,length(alphabets),1)
      names(Index) <- alphabets

      # Notice I don't put the vector in a one row matrix as in you example
      sample(Index,input$samsize)
   })

   library(purrr) # map is a nice alternative to lapply
   output$myTable <- renderUI(map(names(data()),~div(strong(.),
                                                     div(data()[.]),
                                                     style="float:left;padding:10px 20px;")))
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Here is screen shot. As it is seen, *Here is some text* is next to `uioutput` display, which I want to be in a new line below the display [image]

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing any of your CSS or rendered HTML output. But it seems like that `<p>` tag is floating. Can you add the styles `float: none; display: block;` to your `<p>` and see if you get what you want?

Comment: `p("Here is some text...",div(style="float: none; display: block;"))` - did not change output. May I know whether you got any different out when you ran the code on your side? Shiny help file (https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/htmlOutput.html) talks about *inline* feature but could not relate it to to what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After using `div` with style `float:left`, you need to clear the floating, for example with `clear:left`:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  tabPanel("Test",
           numericInput("samsize","specify sample size",4,1,52),
           uiOutput('myTable'),
           div("Here is some text...", style="clear:left;"),
           dateInput("date", label = "Today's Date")
  ))
```

[image: Result using clear:left]

You will find more info about floating `div` [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp)